# swapoff behaviour: what happens when I launch it?

Tags: swap

I am curious about the mechanism behind `swapoff` command;

When I run that command, where do "swapped" data go?

How does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `swapoff` disables a swap device (or file), the data that’s stored there is read back into memory. If there isn’t enough available memory to do so (perhaps by swapping out to another swap device, if any are still available), `swapoff` fails with [exit status 2](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/swapoff.8.html#EXIT_STATUS).

You can watch this in progress by running `vmstat 1` or repeatedly running `swapon` (which shows the occupation of the current swap devices): you’ll see that the swap size of a disabled swap device is reduced to the amount that’s actually in use, and that the amount in use progressively decreases as data is read back in. `vmstat` shows the amount of data read back in in its `si` column.